# Pass Object ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Initially i was trying to pass the object :id to the url it was successful, but after that when i tried to pass the object to the list then it started showing ReferenceError.

index.ejs:

```
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">AWB NO</th>
    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
    <th class="text-center">Supplier</th>
    <th class="text-center">Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="id"><a href="/dist" + AWB_NO>1687952</a></td>
    <td>06/06/2019</td>
    <td>Tropic Frozen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
```

index.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM orders', function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.render('index', { page_title: "index - Node.js", data: '' });
        } else {

            res.render('index', { page_title: "index - Node.js", data: rows });

        }

    })
});
```

dist.ejs:

`<li class="list-inline-item">AWB Number:<%= AWB_NO %></li>` //trying to pass object

dist.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM deliveries', function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.render('dist', { page_title: "dist - Node.js", data: '' });
        } else {

            res.render('dist', { page_title: "dist - Node.js", data: rows });

        }

    })
});

router.get('/:awb', function (req, res) {
    res.render('dist', {
     AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })
});
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: E:\Dev\admeghbalim\YinSeafood\YinSeafood\expressfirst\views\dist.ejs:20
    18|             <h3>Distributor information</h3><br>&nbsp;
    19|             <ul class="list-inline">
 >> 20|                 <li class="list-inline-item">AWB Number:<%= AWB_NO %></li> &nbsp;
    21|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Country:</li>&nbsp;
    22|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Date:</li>&nbsp;
    23|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Sender:</li>&nbsp;

AWB_NO is not defined
```

Comment: <td class="id"><a href="/dist" + AWB_NO>1687952</a></td> Is this work as the URL to display the dist.ejs file and refer to the route('/:awb')?

Comment: Even that also not happening, before my extension was .jade later i moved my project to .ejs. Perhaps when i was working with jade it was working fine with URL as dist/16878. But after when changing my whole project to ejs, above is the error. This is .jade when i was passing object: div
a.name(href="/track/dist") #{AWB_NO}
div

Comment: My idea was to route with parameter from one page to another, as i do not want to push the id to url, instead i need to push the id to list.

Comment: You can try to do as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change like as below:

index.ejs

```
    <tr>
    <th class="text-center">AWB NO</th>
    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
    <th class="text-center">Supplier</th>
    <th class="text-center">Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="id"><a href="/dist/<%= AWB_NO %>">1687952</a></td>
    <td>06/06/2019</td>
    <td>Tropic Frozen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
```

In the index.js, I assume that you pass the value for AWB_NO. Suppose, you have any array or object than you may iterate using the for loop and write like array['AWB_NO']. It depens upon, how you pass the value in render function.
Updated dist.js:

```
  router.get('/dist/:awb',  function (req, res) {
        res.render('dist', {
            AWB_NO: req.params.awb
        })
});
```

dist.ejs:

```
<li class="list-inline-item">AWB Number:<%= AWB_NO %></li>
```

I hope you are able to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! i see the same error now in index.ejs  and dist.ejs "ReferenceError" AWB_NO is not defined. I think the problem with this line  >> 20|                 <li class="list-inline-item">AWB Number:<%= AWB_NO %></li> &nbsp;

Comment: I have just figured out the problem, it is the problem with "dist.js" where when the index.ejs passes the object the dist.js is not able to find the AWB_NO. But i kinda lost after this.

Comment: Please check main question. dist.js

Comment: Have you read the answer properly than you found the answer. I have already written that, I suppose you pass the AWB_NO with render function.